# Is it thread safety, if I pass my HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, HttpSession objects in Util methods?

Tags: java, session, servlets, thread-safety

Suppose I have one repeated task which is going to process [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) or [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) or [HttpServletResponse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) object. This processing may be abstract some data from HttpSession or set/get some attributes in HttpServletRequest/HttpServletResponse.

Here I am giving one example for idea. I want my current logged in UserId from session. for that I am making one Util method in one of Util classes.

```
public static Integer getCurrentLoggedInUserId(HttpSession session)
{
    // here I will process session object and get first User object and
    //after that I will get id from that User Object. This is one repeated task in my app.
}
```

second example for download file.

```
public static void downloadFile(HttpSrvletResponse response)
{
    // here I will set some attribues/parameters in response for download file.
}
```

Now my question is it thread safety to doing this? I mean is it recommended to pass session/request/response objects from controller/servlets to Util classes? If not, what is solution for these kind of repeated  tasks?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead it will be for proper to use a framework and then distribute what ever you want in a way the framework allows you to . I am not sure if [struts2-interceptors](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_interceptors.htm)  is what you need , but frameworks will help you

Comment: Well as you not modifying the objects passed, what is the issue with thread safety?

Comment: Yes @user2310289 I am not modifying any object in my first example.. but see my second example in updated question.. what if this kind of situation is there?

Comment: There is nothing special, just synchronize the objects and they will be singleton by definition (static).

Comment: Thanks user2310289..but which objects should I synchronize? can you give example please, if possible?

Comment: Sorry I was meaning to make the method or part of it synchronized.  Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: Thanks @user2310289 : yes I got your concept about sync objects. But synchronization is used when same object is shared among various threads.. Am I correct? but here I am calling util method from two different controllers/servlets. Then isn't the response object is different for them? so if it is, here no object sharing..right? clarify me if I am incorrect please

Comment: If you have a browser open with two tabs they will pontentially be sharing the same session.  As I originally said 'what is the issue with thread safety? '

Comment: Yes correct @user2310289. but I am not modifying session, just retrieving data from session in my first example.. but I am modifying response object. Is response/request object shared among two requests from two different tabs in same browser?

Comment: Nah - that does not make sense does it

Answer (score 1):

Thread safety concerns data that is shared amongst threads. For example in your case if you obtained the current user and want to store it in a set of todaysUsers, then you must protect data access to that set:

```
private static Set<Integer> todaysUsers = new HashSet<Integer>();

public static Integer getCurrentLoggedInUserId(HttpSession session)
{
    Integer currentUser = ......
    synchronized(todaysUsers) {
         todaysUsers.add(currentUser);
    }
    return currentUser;
}
```

because each thread will call the method with it's own session, this is not data sharing and thus no issue for thread safety

Comment: Hi.. GerritCap thanks a lot..I understood what u said.. for retrieving data only, there is no problem..what about my second example in my updated question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This would be thread safe if the `Util` class has no state.

Usually this isn't done because ideally only the Servlet should know about the request/response objects.

If you are writing a utility class that exclusively acts on the request/response objects consider writing a wrapper class that wraps, say, the request object and then acts on it.

This way you don't have thread safety concerns as you create new wrappers for each request.

Comment: hi..Boris the Spider.. I didn't understand what do you mean by "Util class has no state". Can u please explain or give some example link here?

Comment: and also How to create Wrapper classes on request/response?